# Singleton with a Singleton builder pattern

Tags: c++

I'm familiar with the good ol' Singleton template pattern and use it extensively.  It works well in most cases however, I've hit a case where I have singleton that requires a fairly complex build operation to construct a graph of objects that make up the Singleton.

It's easy to put the build operations into a separate builder class but then how could I create a template that would take this builder class as an argument?  For example, I might have a Singleton that looks like this:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(Bar& bar, Spooge& spooge) :
      _bar(bar),
      _spooge(spooge) {}
    ~Foo() {}

    void doSomething();

private:
   Bar _bar;
   Spooge _spooge;
}
```

And then us it like this:

```
Singleton<Foo>::sharedInstance->doSomething();
```

But obviously I can't do this with a traditional Singleton template because it does not have a no argument constructor.

Assuming I have a class called FooBuilder that does have a noargs constructor, how could I create a Singleton template that allows me to specify this builder class?  Something like:

```
Singleton<Foo, FooBuilder>::sharedInstance->doSomething();
```

BTW: Assume that the arguments being passed into Foo's constructor are not singleton object.  They could be other objects that require complex build operations themselves or other non-singleton objects.

Thanks

Comment: `I'm familiar with the good ol' Singleton template pattern and use it extensively` ... You're fired.

Comment: Badly maintained dependencies is one of main problems of this pattern. As noted by @Dave above - singleton is *in general* not a good pattern. You're trying to overcome its problems with magic instead of just not using the singleton. Also, how is `Foo` a singleton if it has a public constructor?

Comment: Dave: this is a matter of debate with people on both sides of the fence.  It's beyond the scope of this question.  BartoszKP: it's just an example. Whether it's a bad example or not is, again, beyond the scope of this discussion.

Comment: @user1143970 It was a matter of debate 10 years ago. Now, 99% of the time, it's horrible. Try working in any large project with singletons regularly used.

Comment: Perhaps but I think you're jumping to conclusions.  I have to limit some of my classes to a single instance.  I don't have an IoC container to help me manage injections of my objects, so I do it myself. I don't sprinkle Singleton<Blah> through my code, I have it in one place and pass the instance to other objects.  I'm simply trying to write a template to simplify the process of building my "single instance" objects (OK? I didn't use the term "Singleton").

Comment: If the FooBuilder class has knowledge how to populate all the required dependencies then the task becomes pretty easy. In that case FooBuilder can be a simple function object which constructs and returns an instance of the Foo class. Then you can assign the returned value to Singleton::sharedInstance.

Comment: Yeah, but how to I create a template to do that?

Comment: Just a quick and dirty snippet: http://ideone.com/LZYuZ1.